# PDFView's effectiveAppearance not updated when switching to dark mode

Tags: swift, pdfkit, pdfview, macos-darkmode

PDFKit's PDFView seems to not be compatible with dark mode. It's `effectiveAppearance` does not get updated when user switches to dark mode.

```
override public func updateLayer() {
    print("mode = \(effectiveAppearance.name)")
    super.updateLayer()
}
// even in dark mode, always prints: mode = NSAppearanceName(_rawValue: NSAppearanceNameAqua)
```

Is there any reason for that? Any elegant workaround to change PDFView's background color with dark mode?